# Using a PC for communication via GSM - not possible?

Tags: gsm, telecommunication

While wondering what phone to buy after my current one died I came across the idea to use my PC and some kind of "GSM Dongle" to make phone calls and use sms. With my rather limited knowledge of computer systems and the GSM network I thought this should be a realistic possibility. A freely available GSM chipset, a valid sim card, a usb interface and some drivers should be sufficient.

But googling the topic yielded next to no results: Some obscure alibaba sites offer no name gsm dongles, and no one in any forum, blog etc even seems to consider making phone calls via PC.

Since I can't imagine me being the first one to have such an idea, I figured that what I want to achieve is simply not possible. But again, I fail to understand why that would be the case.

Anyone cares to enlighten me on this topic?

Comment: They are called *GSM Modems*, bucket-loads on ebay

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A GSM dongle is designed for making a data connection (internet connection) to a gateway in the operator's network.  The exact technology used won't actually be GSM by the way, it will be GPRS, UMTS or LTE.

SIMs supplied with GSM dongles are typically on data tarifs only, i.e. don't support voice calls.  As you pointed out however, GSM does support voice calls.  To make a voice call, you would need a SIM with a voice call tarif.  Then you need to send commands (e.g. AT commands) to the dongle to dial a voice call, and also have some software to connect the input/output of the voice call to your computer's headphones/speakers.

Probably a simpler way to make calls, is to make a standard internet connection with the dongle, and then use a service like Skype as you would over any IP connection.

You can send SMSes from any GSM dongle with a typical data SIM.  You just need to be on a mobile network, and SMSes are usually included in data tarifs.  You can send SMSes via entering AT commands (write a small program to send them to a COM port, or use some application like Hyperterminal that lets you enter the commands), or programmatically using the Windows Mobile Broadband API (if the dongle appears as a network adapter on your computer).  Some standard Mobile Broadband dashboards from the operators have a GUI for sending SMS.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. So I basically found no solution mainly because no one cared to provide a good software for handling gsm calls.

Comment: @ArturSchmitt Try googling "gsm modem voice call software".  I've just tried to give you an overview to understand the process better, whether you want to enter AT commands, write your own app or look for something else.

Comment: I tried that, and it leads me back to the obscure alibaba sites i stated in the first place. I hope you didn't get me wrong - I really appreciate your post. You clarified a lot, thanks for your time! 
One last thing - when I google for 'gsm modem' in general, basically every product from a renowned manufacturer states 'data call and sms support'. Is voice call a feature I need to specifically watch out for? Or is every gsm modem capable of in- and outgoing voice calls (Provided I have an appropriate software interface)?

Comment: OK, sorry, I didn't follow the links.  Data and voice calls have different quality of service on the GSM air interface.  I don't know if a typical GSM modem actually prevents you from making a voice call - possibly, this is a factory setting.  On the other hand, I do know that voice calls have in the past been offered as a feature, with some extra voice call software, by some operators.  Therefore, I suspect, that there is no setting that prevents voice calls, but it states "data call and sms support" for marketing reasons.  You'd have to do some tests.

Comment: Some interesting stuff about Huawei devices and activating voice calls here: http://www.ruchirablog.com/activating-voice-calling-on-huawei-hspa-modems/